# Unable to find Dell factory restauration partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, dell, backup

I want to restore my DELL Vostro to factory setting but I am not able to find the restauration partition.

I tried to restore GRUB and Windows MBR but both can't access to recovery partition.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10445000/) you can find my boot-repair info.

I've tried Dell Backup and Recovery (I am limited to 2 links in my post, but you could find it easyly on google) but it cannot find my restauration partition.

I've also tried [Restore the computer's software to original condition.](http://www.dell.com/support/article/fr/fr/frbsdt1/SLN117599/EN) but I can't find out Dell Factory Image Restore.

Thank you,

PS: I am a French guy so please be tolerant with my english :)

PS2: I am also a developer so I am not afraid to do some stuff in terminal ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system does not contain any restore partitions:

```
/dev/sda1               2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2    *        206,848   409,806,847   409,600,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         409,808,894   976,771,071   566,962,178   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         409,808,896   968,638,463   558,829,568  83 Linux
/dev/sda6         968,640,512   976,771,071     8,130,560  82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

(from your boot-repair info)

So you'll have to order a Restore DVD from Dell to accomplish what you're trying to do...

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.